# Aggregate data from two different database contexts

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cqrs, onion-architecture

I have two database contexts.

**First:** ASP.NET identity context.

```
public class IdentityContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityAppUser>
{
    public IdentityContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Identity user.

```
public class IdentityAppUser : IdentityUser
{
}
```

**Second:** DatabaseContext.

```
public sealed class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Domain user. Contains identity user id.

```
public class User : BaseEntity
{
    public string IdentityId { get; set; }
}
```

And I am using CQRS. I want to return full user data (identity info + domain model info). So I'm thinking about implementation.

1. Keep two separate queries. First query returns domain user, second returns identity user. Then merge query results on API layer.
2. Keep single query for this purpose. Keep full user model on application layer. Merge domain and identity users into full model in the query handler.
3. Move domain user to the infrastructure layer. Create new domain user model that contains full user info. Keep single query to return full user data. Merge database user model (old domain user) and identity user in the query handler.

Which approach is better?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this problem ultimately is quite similar as returning results of two queries from the same database. The results need to be be merged somewhere. Sometimes it's the repository, sometimes it's the service layer, sometimes the client code makes two calls to the backend to create a single page.

There is no general correct response where to combine data. Sometimes it may be clear (data from two related tables => do it in SQL), sometimes it's less clear.

Please remember that there will likely be several views of the entity (in this case user) used throughout the solution and these views may be combined with other data in different layers of your application.